# How to use a variable in Data step without including it as a column in SAS

Tags: sas

When I use the Data Step, I don't want to include temporary variables as columns. For example, in the following, while I want to include `y` as a column, I don't want to include `a` and `b` as columns. How can I tell SAS to not include `a` and `b` as columns?

```
Data Table1;
Set Table2;
a=scan(column_x,1,'_')
b=scan(column_x,2,'_')
y=cats(a, ':', b)
Run;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

- the `DROP` statement
  `DROP A B;`
- or `(DROP=` data set option
  `DATA Table1(Drop=A B);`
- or `KEEP` statement
- or `(KEEP=` data set option

You would explicitly list the desired variables when coding `KEEP`.